# How to find string with role format in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm want to find string have format like:

```
numbers.H numbers.numbers'
```

Example:

```
1H 34'
4H 89'
```

I tried this code:

```
string format;
int[] numbers = new int[10] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
foreach(var values in numbers)
{
       format = values + "H " + values + values + "'";
}
```

NOTE: this code seems to fail. I code to you can't easy understand my problem.
So, if my `sourceString` have values like: `4H 89'`.

I want to check this values a have format like `numbers.H numbers.numbers'`

At this time, I analysis like:
4 is `numbers`. H . 8 is `numbers`. 9 is `numbers`.  =====> Correct format.

My code can't find this string. Can anybody have any method to resolve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: So the question here is, how to generate all possible combinations of (numbers.H numbers.numbers') and validate `sourceString` is one of them?

Comment: your `format` variable has never a value `4h 89` ?

Comment: Yes, I have input like: `4H 89' or 5H 23'`. I want to find this have correct with format `(numbers.H numbers.numbers)`.

Comment: Use Reqular Expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "9H 99";
if (Regex.Match(input.ToUpper(), @"\d[A-Z]\s\d\d").Success)
{
   //Match
}
else
{
  //Not
}
```

Comment: Both lower and upper case of any letter not just H. you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Can be simplified using `Linq` or `Regex`, may be this can be helpful

```
string[] stringFormat = new string[7] { "1H 34'", "4H 89'", "4H 89", "42 89", "4H 8H'", "345 t3", "4H 333'" };
            List<string> requiredFormattedStrings = new List<string>();
            foreach (var stringValue in stringFormat)
            {
                string[] val = stringValue.Split(' ');
                if ((val[0].Length == 2 && val[0].EndsWith("H")) && (val[1].Length == 3 && val[1].EndsWith("'")))
                {
                    bool isNumber = Char.IsDigit(val[0], 0);
                    if (isNumber)
                    {
                        string secondString = val[1].Substring(0, 2);
                        bool isNumber2 = secondString.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));
                        if(isNumber2)
                        {
                            requiredFormattedStrings.Add(stringValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**OUTPUT**

`1H 34'` ,`4H 89'`

Answer (score 1):

@Dr. Stitch answer is best. If you want to understand the regex pattern.

```
string input = "9H 99";
if (Regex.Match(input.ToUpper(), @"\d\\H [0-9]{2}").Success)
//This is the pattern if you get only H or else replace '\\H' with'[A-Z]'.
//If you also get small case then add [a-zA-Z]
{
   //Match
}
else
{
  //Not
}
```